# How to code a shortest path problem with for cycle in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, shortest-path

I created an actions array and each one of this action has a cost. After this, I implement a for cycle to find the action with the lowest cost. Secondly, I have to check the preconditions to see which action is possible.

```
//Actions
static Action loadPlaneP1 = new Action("loadPlaneP1",pkg1Location[1], pkg2Location[0], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0], 30);
static Action loadPlaneP2 = new Action("loadPlaneP2", pkg1Location[0], pkg2Location[1], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[0], cityLocation[0], 40);
static Action fly = new Action("fly",pkg1Location[1], pkg2Location[1], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[1], cityLocation[0], 100);
static Action unloadPlaneP1 = new Action("unloadPlaneP1",pkg1Location[2], pkg2Location[1], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 50);
static Action unloadPlaneP2 = new Action("unloadPlaneP2",pkg1Location[1], pkg2Location[2], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 55);
static Action loadTruckP1 = new Action("loadTruckP1",pkg1Location[3], pkg2Location[2], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 60);
static Action loadTruckP2 = new Action("loadTruckP2",pkg1Location[2], pkg2Location[3], truckLocation[0], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 10);
static Action drive = new Action("drive",pkg1Location[3], pkg2Location[3], truckLocation[1], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 70);
static Action unloadTruckP1 = new Action("unloadTruckP1", pkg1Location[5], pkg2Location[5], truckLocation[2], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 40);
static Action unloadTruckP2 = new Action("unloadTruckP2",pkg1Location[4], pkg2Location[4], truckLocation[3], planeLocation[2], cityLocation[1], 43);

//Array
static Action[] acts = { loadPlaneP1, loadPlaneP2, fly, unloadPlaneP1, unloadPlaneP2, loadTruckP1, loadTruckP2, drive, unloadTruckP1, unloadTruckP2 };
```

The problem is in the main logic, because when I print the action name and the cost obtained, is showing `loadPlaneP1`(the one with lower cost) but the parameter that I get through `getActParameter1()` is the parameter of `unloadTruckP2`(the last one in the array).

Moreover, if I change the cost to set another action cost to the lowest, the logic doesn't work.

```
//Main logic
System.out.println("Old state parameters are " + "pkg1Location: " + state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " + state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ state.getStateParameter5());

for(int i = 0; acts[i].getActionCost() == getMinValue(costs); i++) {
    System.out.println("PRE The first parameter is : " + acts[i].getActParameter1() + acts[i].name);

    if(acts[i].getActParameter1() == "plane") {
        System.out.println("POST The first parameter is : " + acts[i].getActParameter1());
        System.out.println("Precondition satysfied" + " with action name: " + acts[i].name);

        if(acts[i].getActParameter1() != state.getStateParameter1()) {
            state.setStateParameter1(acts[i].getActParameter1());
        }

        if(acts[i].getActParameter2() != state.getStateParameter2()) {
            state.setStateParameter2(acts[i].getActParameter2());
        }

        if(acts[i].getActParameter3() != state.getStateParameter3()) {
            state.setStateParameter3(acts[i].getActParameter3());
        }

        if(acts[i].getActParameter4() != state.getStateParameter4()) {
            state.setStateParameter4(acts[i].getActParameter4());
        }

        if(acts[i].getActParameter5() != state.getStateParameter5()) {
            state.setStateParameter5(acts[i].getActParameter5());
        }
    }

    Node child = new Node(state, startNode, acts[i].getActionCost());

    /*  List<Action> removeList = new ArrayList<Action>(Arrays.asList(acts));
        removeList.remove(Arrays.asList(i));
        acts = removeList.toArray(acts);*/

    //nextAction = acts[i];
    System.out.println("Costs array: "+  Arrays.toString(costs));
    System.out.println("ActionID" +" " +  i);
    System.out.println("The action choosen is " + acts[i].name + acts[i].actionCost + acts[i].getActParameter1());
    System.out.println("State parameters updated are " + "pkg1Location: " + state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " + state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ state.getStateParameter5());
    };

}
```

The output that I receive is

```
Old state parameters are pkg1Location: lhr pkg2Location: lhr truckLocation: cdg planeLocation: lhr cityLocation:london
PRE The first parameter is : southloadPlaneP1
POST The first parameter is : south
Precondition satysfied with action name: loadPlaneP1
Costs array: [30, 40, 100, 50, 55, 60, 70, 70, 40]
ActionID 0
The action choosen is loadPlaneP130south
State parameters updated are pkg1Location: south pkg2Location: south truckLocation: south planeLocation: cdg cityLocation:paris
```

So the condition is not satisfied, because the parameter that I get from `getActParameter1()` is different from the one that `loadPlaneP1` has.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would say the problem is your for loop. It only iterates if the cost of the act. action is equal to the minimal cost in the cost array. If for the first iteration this condition is not valid, the for loop breaks.

Comment: That condition in the for is not like "go on until you find the one with the lowest cost?"

Comment: If the condition in the middle of a for loop is not valid the for loop ends. If you do not understand for loops, how could you write this program? Sorry, but these are basics, you should know before start programming in a language. `for ( int i = 0 ; i < acts.length - 1; i++ ) { ... }` for example iterates over all actions then test with `if` if the condition is true and perform the calculations.

Comment: Yes but I have tried to code **for(int i = 0; i <acts.lenght; i++)** and in this way I obtain that is printing 10 times (the number of actions) always the last action parameter and name. Only the cost and the action ID are changing

Comment: That's because i'v written you should test (`if` statement ) in the for loop if the condition is true. `for(...) {  if ( acts[i].getActionCost() == getMinValue(costs) ) { ... the other if statements and the prints ... } }`

Comment: Yes I understand, but I'm not implementing the if condition. I'm just using the for cycle like that and I obtain always the same action printed

Comment: I do not understand. I say you should test with an `if` statement, and you say you won't?  To shorten that, I'll give you an answer with the for if contruct. But be aware, that I have not looked through your inner code line. They might also be wrong. That's why I preferred  to write comments.

Comment: I was saying that I'm trying only with the for before implement also the if condition. But already with that is printing always the same parameter and action name, only cost and actionID are changing. Anyway thanks

Comment: You're welcome. But would you answer your question with the final solution and mark it as the accepted solution. If you don't your question will be marked as not answered and this leads to some action that cost some people time. If my answer is correct you can mark this too. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see with your code is the for loop condition, that stops the loop if the actual cost is not the minimal cost. So, if in the first iteration the actual cost is not equal to the minimal cost, the for loop is never iterated. I have not tried to find out what you do in the for loop. There may be more errors.

```
for( int i = 0; i < acts.length -1; i++ ) 
{
   if ( acts[i].getActionCost( ) == getMinValue( costs ) )
   { 
     System.out.println( "PRE The first parameter is : " +  
                        acts[i].getActParameter1() + acts[i].name );

     if ( acts[i].getActParameter1() == "plane" ) 
     {
        System.out.println( "POST The first parameter is : " + 
                            acts[i].getActParameter1() );
        System.out.println( "Precondition satysfied with action name: " + 
                            acts[i].name );

        if ( acts[i].getActParameter1() != state.getStateParameter1() ) 
        {
          state.setStateParameter1( acts[i].getActParameter1() );
        }

        if(acts[i].getActParameter2() != state.getStateParameter2()) 
        {
          state.setStateParameter2( acts[i].getActParameter2() );
        }

        if( acts[i].getActParameter3() != state.getStateParameter3() ) 
        {
          state.setStateParameter3( acts[i].getActParameter3() );
        }

        if( acts[i].getActParameter4() != state.getStateParameter4() ) 
        {
          state.setStateParameter4( acts[i].getActParameter4() );
        }

        if( acts[i].getActParameter5() != state.getStateParameter5() ) 
        {
          state.setStateParameter5( acts[i].getActParameter5() );
        }
    }

    Node child = new Node(state, startNode, acts[i].getActionCost());

    System.out.println( "Costs array: "+  Arrays.toString( costs ) );
    System.out.println( "ActionID" +" " +  i );
    System.out.println( "The action choosen is " + acts[i].name + 
                        acts[i].actionCost + acts[i].getActParameter1() );
    System.out.println( "State parameters updated are " + "pkg1Location: " + 
                        state.getStateParameter1() + " pkg2Location: " +
                        state.getStateParameter2() + " truckLocation: "+ 
                        state.getStateParameter3() + " planeLocation: " + 
                        state.getStateParameter4() + " cityLocation:"+ 
                        state.getStateParameter5());
  }
}
```